# Is it safe to change MSparseArrays which lack column indices?

Tags: sparse-arrays, librarylink

I am using sparse arrays with LibraryLink.  I noticed that when [`MSparseArray_fromExplicitPositions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/ref/callback/MSparseArray_fromExplicitPositions.html) and [`MSparseArray_fromMTensor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/ref/callback/MSparseArray_fromMTensor.html) return an all-zero sparse array, the corresponding `MSparseArray` will have neither an explicit values vector nor a column indices vector. There is a null pointer in place of both.

It is documented that this may be the case for explicit values (pattern arrays don't have them).  But it is not documented that *the column indices* may also be missing.  In fact not even the included example program (`demo_sparse.c`) is prepared for this eventuality (and will crash if such a sparse array is passed to it).  Mathematica itself never passes such an `MSparseArray` to the library. Thus I think the behaviour is a bug.

**What I need is a convenient workaround.  Is it safe to manually insert an empty (but non-`NULL`!) column indices vector into the `MSparseArray` data structure?**

Example:

```c
MTensor *ci = libData->sparseLibraryFunctions->MSparseArray_getColumnIndices(msa);

if (*ci == NULL) {
    mint dims[2] = {0, libData->sparseLibraryFunctions->MSparseArray_getRank(msa)};
    libData->MTensor_new(MType_Integer, 2, dims, ci);
}
```

Is it safe to do this for every single `MSparseArray` in my program, *even for those that were passed as `"Constant"` from the kernel*?

---

I am using a C++ wrapper class for sparse arrays, and it would be most convenient to simply do this correction in the constructor of that class.

Also note that while I have not found a way to create such a problematic sparse array directly in Mathematica, if a LibraryLink library returns one, it will stay in that form. That means that in principle someone else's library may generate such a sparse array, which may then be passed to my own library.  This means that I absolutely need to be prepared for getting a "Constant" sparse array with no column indices as an input to my library, and I need to have explicit checks for it so that I don't accidentally call functions like `MTensor_getFlattenedLength` on `NULL` and crash the kernel.  If I cannot normalize the sparse array structure by manually replacing the column indices when needed, then I would have to have these checks at almost every place in the program that manipulates sparse arrays, which would be extremely inconvenient.